# Two executable files - Java - Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, build

I finished my socket programming project, and it is requested to have two executables for windows, one being the client app and the other the server app.

I do have two main classes of course, one for the Server.java and one for the Client.java, but I cannot figure out how to like export my project and have to .exe files.

And when they run it, will a cmd open for each one just like testing in NetBeans - my IDE choice to build the project ?

I have been researching the and trying for the past hour and the deadline is tonight.
Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Several solutions: [How to Create an Executable JAR with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven)

Comment: But for two .exes file in 1 project how to do it i cannot figure it out....

Comment: Nobody would do that.

Comment: You could have a single `main` that accepts an argument like `-c` for client and `-s` for server and then calls the correct method for that argument.